# Regex to match only if two sequences are identical

Tags: java, regex

Is it possible to write a Java Regex sequence to match two identical sequences within a string. In other words given the string

```
near[2015-12-1] far[2015-12-1]
```

I want to match all strings where the value inside the first square brackets is equal to the one in the second square bracket and the strings outside the square brackets are `near[] far[]`.

```
near[2015-12-1] far[2015-12-1] MATCH
near[2015-12-3] far[2015-12-1] NO MATCH
near[2015-12-1] far[2014-12-1] NO MATCH
near[2015-12-3] far[2015-12-3] MATCH
foo[2015-12-1] bar[2015-12-1] NO MATCH
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use capturing group and you should refer those captured characters by back-reference.

```
"^near\\[(.*?)\\]\\sfar\\[\\1\\]$"
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/fA1xE5/1)

Comment: Perfect thanks, I knew it was something like that but couldn't get it right and this worked first time.

Comment: The anchors (`^$`) are unnecessary, assuming you use `matches()`.

Answer (score 3):

The regular expression would look something like `near\[(.*)\] far\[\1\]`. In Java, you'd have something like the following:

```
Pattern.matches("near\\[(.*)\\] far\\[\\1\\]", "near[2015-12-1] far[2015-12-1]")
```

or

```
"near[2015-12-1] far[2015-12-1]".matches("near\\[(.*)\\] far\\[\\1\\]")
```